# What is the best way to build an api for huge list and retrieve it via vuejs

Tags: wordpress, api, vue.js, vuex

I have a wordpress site that i need to build an api for it that retrieve all posts from a custom post type.
My problems are so and i would like to have ideas or solutions for best practice.

The custom post type has around 100 000 Post which is too big.

1-So i thought i can build an api that send 100 post with every call (Just change the parameter of the numbers)
Is this right or do i have to think on a better way ?

2-After building the api i want to send the data to vuejs table ?
Here i have a problem and i cannot found a solution of how to get all posts there or to get them grouped 100 post on every group.
If i received them as 100 post on every group how to do to call the next group when i go to the second page on the table or when i search on the table.

Note:
Am using vue bootstrap tables and vuex.

Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Pagination is the best to handle a lot of data at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can send 100 posts at a time when fetching the next 100 posts you can send the last posts Id and use it as a cursor (Asuming you are using SQL based database but then with a little tweak it works for NoSql databases too) to fetch the post in a efficient way

You can overwrite the posts global variable  to make the webpage more efficient in terms of memory unless you want the post to be stored in some Local storage and parse them if the posts are not like very frequently updated

In routing you can use a dynamic value to set the cursor so that you can group the posts as 100 and use it to traverse through them